# How to add an answer to this topic ? https://superuser.com/questions/258287/how-can-i-export-a-directory-structure

Tags: discussion

I'm a new user, I can't add my answer to this topic: [How can I export a directory structure?](https://superuser.com/questions/258287/how-can-i-export-a-directory-structure)

I want to write the best solution: Visual CD

Answer (score 7):

> I'm a new user, I can't add my answer to this topic: How can I export a directory structure?

You will be unable to answer [How can I export a directory structure?](https://superuser.com/questions/258287/how-can-i-export-a-directory-structure) at this time due to having an insignificant reputation to answer protected questions.  The question was also closed due to the fact it was seeking a software recommendation.  The question was closed due to the fact, it over the last 8 years, has seen 9 answers deleted.

> I want to write the best solution: Visual CD

Before you make software recommendations, be sure to read the help center, to better understand what the community will expect out of a software recommendation.  In most cases, if a question is seeking a software recommendation, it is simply out of scope, and shouldn't even be answered.  However, there are times where it is appropriate to recommend software to accomplish a goal, and the communities expectation is higher than just what you believe is the best solution.  For instance, in this case, you would need to be able to provide statements to back up the reason `Visual CD` "is the best solution".  *Answers that do not provide a reason, for the recommendation, are very likely to be deleted.*  While we value every appropriate recommendation, an answer that says something is simply "the best", isn't really helpful to the community.

Questions that seek a software recommendation should either be migrated [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or simply be closed due to the fact they are out of scope here at Super User.  In this case, the existing question, cannot be migrated due to its age so it was simply closed.  *Questions that are out of scope should not be answered.*

Comment: Thanks, will take note. Didn't know we could not recommend software here.

Comment: I was in fact looking for this solution (Visual CD) when searching google.

Comment: @ken - You can recommend software but really should be based on something other than your opinion.

Comment: *...If a question is seeking a software recommendation, it is simply out of scope, and **shouldn't even be answered***. I couldn't agree more. Disappointingly even some of our higher rep users can't seem to avoid the temptation to do so.

Answer (score 4):

That question has been protected. You need at least 10 [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) to answer it.

You can gain reputation (you only need 9 more!) by asking good questions, or by answering other (non-protected) questions.

Look around and find a few other questions you can answer. It won't take long to get to 10 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

The question was protected due to receiving many low quality or spammy answers. As mentioned by Doug this means you needed 10 reputation to post an answer.

The question itself was off topic by our [current rules](https://superuser.com/help). Simply asking for product recommendations is off topic here and the question has been closed.